# Terminating a Screen session after running "screen -D -m"

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a screen running with a number of sessions, and in one of them, I entered `screen -D -m` and now that session is just hung. I can't do an Escape, q, or Ctrl+C to terminate. Even after closing and resuming the screen `screen -r screenName`, this specific session is just in that same state.

How do I kill this session? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen -D -m` starts a *new* session in a detached state without forking a new process.  The command will not terminate until that new screen exits.

You can still put the command in the background with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> followed by `bg`, and then check what name it got with `screen -ls` (it will say `(Detatched)` at the end and also mention the time it was created). The name is the first word on one of the lines and will likely contain some digits and your hostname.

Attach to the session with `screen -r name` (where `name` is the name shown by `screen -ls` for the started session that you'd like to end) and exit from it.

You don't need to exit or detach from the original `screen` session to do any of these things.

Comment: cool thanks! i didn't realize i just have to look it up by `screen -ls` on the actual host that that session was in.